# Run function for specific user only

Tags: functions, admin-css

I've created following function to run a stylesheet for the admin area, but I want to runt it only for 'shop_manager' this user role and for others, it should not make any modifications from that stylesheet.

```
// Update CSS within in Admin
function admin_style() {
    if (current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        return admin_style();
    }
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```

Problem with it is, when I put shop_manager in user role section it loads only shop_manager's admin dashboard and not the Administrator's. And when I add `! current_user_can` it happens the same but vice versa. Please help!!

Comment: Thanks for providing the sample code you are using. It looks like you have a recursive function in there so behavior is probably not what you expect. Instead of returning admin_style(), shouldn't you be returning false or an empty string or something? I'm struggling to understand your intentions with this code.

Comment: Thanks and sorry my bad that I didn't return blank (false), now I remove admin_style() and write only return; and it worked.